# 'output' does not exist in model 'file:///android_asset/retrained_graph.pb'

Tags: android, tensorflow

I was retrain a inception model with food images,
I got the final test prediction and `retrained_graph.pb` ,`retrained_labels.txt` file.
I check the prediction using command prompt in windows and its work.
But i was put the `retrained_graph.ph and retrained_labels.
Txt` files into android studio asset folder for deploying mobile,i got the 
exception:
`output does not exist in model file:///android_asset/retrained_graph.pb`

Can anyone help me solve this issue.

Comment: No. Impossible. It is unclear what you are doing. What does this have to do with programming? I see no code.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your output node name is not 'output' but something else. Go back to your training script and print out the node names, then copy the output node name exactly as it is there to your Android Studio project.